# XML Divide by 1000

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm having trouble when I try to divide a text field by 1000. Currently it's set to Millimetres but I need it to be set to metres. I thought by dividing the text field by 1000 it would do this but it throws the following error.

```
There was an exception while running the report 
An exception occurred while creating a report. 
root-cause=class groovy.lang.MissingMethodException/No signature of method: java.lang.String.div() 
is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [1000]"
```

The code for XML is as following:

```xml
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{EquipmentLengthMm} /1000]]></textFieldExpression>
```

I think I may require a variable expression to complete this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing this in iReport or creating the jrxml manually? If the field is of type integer then EquipmentLengthMm/1000 should be a valid expression.

You can change the report default scripting language from groovy to java or javascript so use what you are most comfortable with. If you select the report at the top level of the tree and look into properties you can see language there.

Edit - the following works fine for me in Groovy but not in Java, I guess due to a type conversion error. Here is my xml if you are interested. Note number fields would be big decimal by default not integer (with oracle at least):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test_UTC_conv" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="d86eb2f0-88fe-4b24-8f1e-3de8dc4116a4">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select 1 as col1
from dual
]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COL1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="9c3a86a8-43d4-45df-bbcf-9877cc60f8d1" x="23" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[COL1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="12b0d8a4-78a6-44ca-ad0a-a663e00a4e45" x="123" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="10f0849d-bf16-48b0-b7c9-a1ef3c141638" x="223" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL1}/1000]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="49e2363e-a693-4f4e-aa77-3b168df302e5" x="307" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL1}/1000]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```